# Extraction and Validation

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I am working on a project which is based on the nest.js framework

The following is a snippet of my function:

```
  @Post('beneficiaries/:beneficiaryId/bankDetails')
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  async addBankDetails(@Param('beneficiaryId', new ValidationPipe()) beneficiaryHash: BeneficiaryHashIdDto, @Body() body, @Headers() headers) {
    const beneficiary = await this.beneficiaryService.getBeneficiaryIdFromHash(beneficiaryHash, ['beneficiaryId', 'currencyCode', 'countryCode']);
    let routingOptions = await this.beneficiaryService.getBeneficiaryRoutingConfig(beneficiary.beneficiaryId, pick(headers, GET_HEADERS_LIST));
    routingOptions = lmap(routingOptions, partialRight(pick, ['bankDetail', 'beneficiaryRoutingConfigId']));
    const [routingConfig] = routingOptions.filter(item => item.beneficiaryRoutingConfigId === body.beneficiaryRoutingConfigId);
    if (!routingConfig) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Invalid beneficiaryRoutingConfigId');
    }
    const { error } = this.beneficiaryService.bankDetailsSchema(routingConfig.bankDetail).validate(body, { abortEarly: false });
    if (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException(error);
    }

    // write here logic to validate routing codes
    await this.beneficiaryService.validateBeneficiaryBankDetails(routingConfig, body, pick(headers, GET_HEADERS_LIST), beneficiary);
    // write here logic to insert bank details of bene
    return this.beneficiaryService.updateBankDetails(body, headers, beneficiary.beneficiaryId);
  }
```

Nest allows us to extract the params, headers, body, etc of a request.

https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers

I want to extract a particular key from my params

For example my params contain:
1.clientId
2.customerId
3.beneficiaryId

I am able to take out the beneficiaryId and store it in beneficiaryHash but I am not able to perform a validation at the same time.Is there any work around?

Answer (score 1):

You can reach it by custom pipes. as a example like ParseIntPipe

```js
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ParseIntPipe implements PipeTransform<string, number> {
  transform(value: string, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): number {
    const val = parseInt(value, 10);
    if (isNaN(val)) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
    }
    return val;
  }
}
```

```js
@Get(':id')
async findOne(@Param('id', new ParseIntPipe()) id) {
  return this.catsService.findOne(id);
}
```

for more knowledge please read https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#transformation-use-case